# MySQL connection Refused from a particular IP address

Tags: mysql

I have a remote server say 1.2.3.4 where I run a code to connect to MySQL which is on another (third) remote server. Now the piece of code runs perfectly fine from my local machine (It connects to Mysql on the Remote server), and that piece of code runs well from two other different IP addresses also.

But only from 1.2.3.4 server when I try to connect to MySQL it gives this Error:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '45.105.149.250' (110)")

What can be the Issue ?

Comment: Its possible theres a firewall blocking to the mysqlserver from the your "1.2.3.4" server?

Comment: @BugFinder but y blocking only 1.2.3.4 ? my IP is also dynamic and changes every day. It never blocked me.

Comment: Depends too much on the 1.2.3.4, for example, if that was my home pc, then if I havent enabled the port for mySQL out, then it wont happen. It could be a routing issue for that range 1.2.3.4 is on, OR, it could be that something on that machine tried too many false accesses and got blocked (I managed to block myself from my website that way)

Comment: Thanks That was the answer ! @BugFinder Respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `telnet` to the server port 3306 and see if it goes through.

That will tell you if it's MySQL that has the issue or something else.

Comment: When I tried to telnet MySQL 3306 from Server 1.2.3.4 It didnt go through but from my local machine it goes through

Comment: Be more specific about "didn't go through". Did it just hang for a while then timeout? Did it tell you "Connection refused"? I can't solve the problem, but those things will tell you where to look for the issue.

Comment: It said " telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out "

Comment: @HussainNagri OK, that usually means a firewall, but it could be other things too. For example the ISP could be blocking that port. Just for fun try `telnet` to other ports to see if you are totally blocked, or if it's just certain ports. Remember I can't solve the issue, I can only help you look.

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate this. I also dont want to be spoon feeded. All I need is some Directions.